# Regular Expression. remove all letters until it sees _

Tags: java, android, regex

I am quite new to java regular expression and since i know about it, I am so amazed how it could help save us time to perform such desired pattern esp string. is there a regex that is used to remove all letters until it meets the underscore `_` symbol? removal also include the `_` symbol.

for example, if string with  `"makesome_cash"`, i need the regex to remove the letters so it will only become `"cash"`.

TQ

Comment: Do you need a regex for this?  Split it on `_`?

Comment: This is a terrible use for a regex. Use `String.indexOf()` to find the `_` and `String.substring()` to return the portion after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
your_string = your_string.replaceAll("^([^_]+_)(.*)", "$2");
```

This will remove anything until it reaches the first `_`, and replace the while `String` with just the second parenthesis match.

Comment: You shouldn't add `.*` at the end as it will also delete all characters after the `_`

Comment: You're right, updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Without using any regex you can do:

```
String s = "makesome_cash";
String r = s.substring(s.indexOf('_')+1); // cash
```

Answer (score 1):

[**`String#split`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) split and get the first index in the ouput array.

```
String text = "makesome_cash";
String matches[]=text.split("_");
System.out.print(matches[1]);
```